# fail to start mongodb-linux-2.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, database

I have downloaded the mongodb-linux-2.4.1 tarball. Then I untar it. go to mongodb-linux-2.4.1/bin folder and start it by

```
./mongo
```

Then I got:

```
li@li-HP:~/Tools/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.1/bin$ ./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.1
connecting to: test
Fri Mar 29 19:29:47.958 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to 
server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./mongo` just run mongodb client
`./mongod` run mongodb server